# MediaRecorder.Stop() fails on Samsung devices such as Galaxy A7, Galaxy A10s etc

Tags: android, mediarecorder

I am using the following settings to initialize `MediaRecorder`. My app is working fine on most devices except Samsung and an error occurs on `MediaRecorder.stop()`.

```
    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(16*44100);
    recorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
```

it throws the following error message.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
at android.media.MediaRecorder._stop (MediaRecorder.java)
at android.media.MediaRecorder.stop (MediaRecorder.java:1440)
at com.appname.stopRecording (add_new.java:4)`
```

Could this be because I am using MIC as an audio source for Samsung devices instead of VOICE_CALL?

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this? seeing the same thing, also only on Samsung

Comment: 1. Please add the whole stacktrace and some extra code
2. Check prepare() executes successfully
3. finally its a IllegalstateException on stop so I assume your start() hasn't started properly

Answer (score 2):

Try doing it this way.

```
recorder = new MediaRecorder();
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
recorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(16*44100);
recorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
recorder.prepare();
recorder.start();   // Recording is now started
```

And when you are trying to stop, do it like this if you arent already.

```
recorder.stop();
recorder.reset();   // You can reuse the object by going back to setAudioSource() step
recorder.release(); // Now the object cannot be reused
```

So, if you call recorder.stop(); before calling recorder.start(); if will show the exception.
And also please check if you have added the permission in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

Comment: At least in my use-case all of the above is true (apart from the difference in codec/format) — it works on all devices but hitting issues with Samsung

Comment: Try following this link it might help. Otherwise please share the code so that i can further assist you.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60235317/14884388

Comment: @anotherdave see my answer below